# How to upload file to GoogleDrive with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-drive-api, dropbox

I got stuck that I cannot upload files to GoogleDrive with AngularJS. Now my client want to know they want to upload a file to Google Drive & Dropbox with AngularJS. Please let me know how to implement?

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get solution to your problem of uploading files to google drive ??

Comment: currently, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

About Google Drive, you can use the Google JS Client, check the JS [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/js) and [how to work with files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive  which provides Drive integration for AngularJS. It includes support for resumeable uploads and chunked uploads so you can display a progress bar for large files.

There is a demo app at https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive-demo.

The demo snippet for a file upload is

```
DriveService.files.insertWithContent(
  {
   title: 'myfile.txt',
   mimeType: 'text/plain'
  },
  { uploadType: 'resumable' },
  content,
  undefined).promise
    .then(function (resp) {
       console.log('finished');
    }, function (reason) {
       console.warn('upload failed because '+reason);
    }, function (position) {
       console.log('Uploading...   Currently at ' + position);
    });
```